# Get text from previous row after clicking button in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen a lot of answers to similar questions but none of them worked and I don't know what to do.

I have a table that dynamically appends rows.
some of the rows have `class="idRow"`.

I need to get the text value of that row after I click a button that is a few rows down (a different location each time but always below the `idRow`, the buttons are located in different rows each time, I don't know which exact row I need when I click a button, just the one that is closest above it)

I know the row is appended and has the text value .
my problem is getting it by clicking the button.

I've tried a lot of options like

```
 alert($(".comnowBtn").parent().closest('tr').prev("#idRow").text());
```

I tried adding `"parent()"`, removing it , `prev`, `closest` , `$("this")` instead of `$(".comnowBtn")`, they all comeback empty.

In one of the iterations I managed to get the row content but it was when I  addressed the whole table and just got all of the `idRow` rows .

Please help!
Thank you!

*I didn't explain myself well the first time, I edited the question.
Thank you!

EDIT:
for everyone wondering what I did-
I couldn't get "closest" ot "prev" to work, so I appended the idRow after the button row (so that the idRow is always below the button) and used-

```
alert(   $(this).parents("tr").next(".idRow").text());
```

it works , but it's a workaround...so if anyone has any idea why "closest" or "prev" don't work, I'll be happy to hear it.
Thank you!

Comment: ID's are unique, so there should only be one element with that ID, which makes this really easy, all you need is `$("#idRow").text()`

Comment: right, it has unique id-s like idRow1,idRow2 and so on and it also has a class="idRow" the problem is that when I click the button I don't know which row I need - could be idRow1 , could be 5....it depends on the location of the button clicked (the button is located all over the table)

Answer (score 1):

Identifier `id` should be unique in same document so try to replace all the duplicate ids by general class, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('body').on('click', '.comnowBtn', function(){
    alert( $(this).closest('tr').prev('.idRow').text() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr class='idRow'><td>idRow row text 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td><button class='comnowBtn'>comnowBtn 1</button></td></tr>
  <tr class='idRow'><td>idRow row text 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td><button class='comnowBtn'>comnowBtn 2</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

---

If you have unique ids like `idRow1` and `idRow2` ... You could use attribute selector with start by sign `^`:

```
$(this).closest('tr').prev("tr[id^='idRow']").text();
```

```js
$('body').on('click', '.comnowBtn', function(){
    alert( $(this).closest('tr').prev("tr[id^='idRow']").text() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr id='idRow2'><td>idRow row text 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td><button class='comnowBtn'>comnowBtn 1</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some extra rows</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some extra rows</td></tr>
  <tr id='idRow2'><td>idRow row text 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td><button class='comnowBtn'>comnowBtn 2</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you're right, I edited the question to better explain the problem

Comment: This answer not resolving your problem?

Comment: I checked but unfortunately - no :( originally I had no <td> because I append things to the <tr> (var row="<tr>......"). I added the <td> but it still doesn't work

Comment: It's not a valid HTML if you're not using `td` and the Browser will add them automatically.

Comment: Make sure that you're using event delegation `on()` in click event like i have in my answer since you deal with fresh DOM added dynamically/

Comment: Thank you ^_^    *the fiddle is just an example of the code . btw- if I ask for  $('#table').find('.idRow').text()  it gives me  the text of all the idRow rows... so it can read them, just have to find the right combination ....

Comment: Still can't get it to work, but I'll keep trying! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: "closest" and "prev" do not work, only "next"- see the edit I added in the question...so weird....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102135/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-alex-k).